# I am randomly generating destination IPs and destination port in python. if destination Ip repeats itself there should be same port for the IP

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

//This is code to generate random destination ip

```py
def destinationipv4(no_ips,no_ops):
    list2=[]
    for i in range(0,no_ips):        
        netwrk_id = np.random.choice(range(100,255),replace=True)
        host_id = np.random.choice(range(100,255),replace=True)
        ip_address_gen = f'192.168.{netwrk_id}.{host_id}'
        list2.append(ip_address_gen)
    return list(np.random.choice(list2,size=no_ops, replace=True))
```

//This is code to generate random port number

```py
def dst_port(n):
    list4=[]
    for i in random.sample(range(0, 1200), n):
        list4.append(i)
    return list4
```

//currently I am getting output as

```
Destination IP      Port
192.168.158.102     458 
192.168.158.102     8
```

where as if IP is same we should get same port number

Comment: Use a dict of {IP: port}?

Comment: The output is working as intended. You asked the compiler to give you a random ip address and a random port number.  I think you are missing some kind of corrolation or math equation between the input 'Destination IP' and 'Port'

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to generate a random list of IP address with random list of port number but if the value of IP address repeats the port number should also repeat for example  Destination IP      Port
192.168.158.102     458 
192.168.158.108     8 
192.168.158.125     358 
192.168.158.102     458